# How to make a copy of a Gurobi model in Python?

Tags: python, gurobi

Suppose I have made a Gurobi model in Python `model = Model()`, defined variables, constraints, objective function, and solved it. However, I want to make a deepcopy of `model` denoted as `new_model`. How should I make a deepcopy of this model? I have tried `new_model = copy.deepcopy(model)`, but it causes an error `KeyError: '__deepcopy__'`.

Comment: How about this? https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/py_model_copy.html

Comment: Thank you. But, when I want to add more constraints,  it results in an error "GurobiError: Variable not in model"

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37307643) question and answer are directly related to your question. But you can also look at Gurobi's discussion about copying a model in its own [website](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360051091912-Can-model-copy-also-copy-my-own-data-structures-of-variables-in-the-original-model-in-Python-), or [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gurobi/Q_d0Qdk_sFk) google group. In summary, you need to name your variable, and after copying the model remap your variable with those names(which need to be saved before).

```
from gurobipy import Model
# A model with 10 variables...
variable_names = {}
model = Model("test")
variables = {}
for i in range(10):
    variable_names[i] = "var{0}".format(i)
    variables[i] = model.addVar(lb=-1, ub=1, name=variable_names[i])
model.update()

new_model = model.copy()
new_var = {}
for i in range(10):
    model.addConstr(variables[i] <= 0)
    new_var[i] = new_model.getVarByName(variable_names[i])
    new_model.addConstr(new_var[i] >= 0)
model.update()
new_model.update()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But, what if we define variables as Y = model.addVars(J, N, vtype=GRB.BINARY,  name='Y_Variable')

Comment: I think whatever you have in the declaration of each variable, is iterable and can be done inside a loop. If you have more than one index, maybe two nested loops.